# Does the number operator $N$ of the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator commute with $x$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

Does the number operator $N$ of the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator commute with $x$?

Comment: It is not proportional, up to a shift, to the oscillator hamiltonian? What do you *see*?

Answer (score 1):

The number operator does not commute with the position operator. We have $$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\hat{X}^2=\left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega=\left(\hat{N}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega$$
Then, $$\hat{N}=\frac{\hat{H}}{\hbar\omega}-\frac{1}{2}$$
where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian for the harmonic oscillator.

Using $[\hat{X},\hat{P}]=i\hbar$, $[\hat{X},\hat{H}]$ is $$\begin{align}[\hat{X},\hat{H}]&=\hat{X}\hat{H}-\hat{H}\hat{X}\\
&=\frac{1}{2m}\hat{X}\hat{P}^2+\frac{1}{2}m\omega\hat{X}^3 -\left(\frac{1}{2m}\hat{P}^2\hat{X}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\hat{X}^3\right) \\
&=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\hat{P}+\frac{1}{2m}\hat{P}\hat{X}\hat{P}+\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\hat{P}-\frac{1}{2m}\hat{P}\hat{X}\hat{P} \\
&= \frac{i\hbar}{m}\hat{P}
\end{align}$$
Now, we can calculate $[\hat{X}, \hat{N}]$:
\begin{align}
[\hat{X},\hat{N}]&=\hat{X}\hat{N}-\hat{N}\hat{X} \\
&=\frac{\hat{X}\hat{H}}{\hbar\omega}-\frac{\hat{X}}{2}-\left(\frac{\hat{H}\hat{X}}{\hbar\omega}-\frac{\hat{X}}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\left(\hat{X}\hat{H}-\hat{H}\hat{X}\right) \\
&= \frac{i}{m\omega}\hat{P}
\end{align}
So no, they do not commute.

Comment: A small correction: $\hat{X}\hat{P}^2 = i\hbar \hat{P} + \hat{P}\hat{X}\hat{P}$, not $\hat{X}\hat{P}^2 = i\hbar + \hat{P}\hat{X}\hat{P}$, and a similar correction has to be done for $\hat{P}^2 \hat{X} $.

Comment: Ach! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!